# Woocommerce shortcode pagination

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Recent products shortcode, `[recent_products per_page="4" columns="2"]`
and would like to have pagination, because I'm displaying products on homepage - and currently only 4 products are being displayed. Is there a way to add pagination?

I have imported dummy data, so there are 45 products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider a plugin: [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/). In order to use it with Woocommerce, simply install and configure the plugin, then add the following code to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
function woocommerce_pagination() {
    wp_pagenavi();      
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
```

Source: [Mark van der Putten's blog](http://www.markvanderputten.com/how-to-add-custom-pagination-to-your-woocommerce/), comments ommitted.

Also, you could ask this question on the dedicated [StackExchange Wordpress site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 7):

Use `[recent_products limit="12" columns="4" paginate="true"]` This shortcode limit 12 means maximum 12 post on a page.
more info [woocommerce doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)

Comment: This is not working for me. the page shows 12 products but no pagination

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal do you have more than 12 products?

Comment: Yes indeed.! I'm using electro woocommerce theme, hopefully theme not affect to this matter.

Comment: it working fine my site, i just test it. maybe your theme have an issue. take a look i just check for you https://karughor.com/shortcode-test/

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from this github gist https://gist.github.com/klihelp/7810337 Including the following code into your child-theme functions.php after installing this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/prime-strategy-page-navi/

```
<?php
/**
 * This code shows pagination for WooCommerce shortcodes when it's embeded on single pages.
 * Include into functions.php.
 */
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
// ---------------------- FRONTPAGE -------------------
if ( defined('WC_VERSION') ) {
// ---------------------- WooCommerce active -------------------

    /**
     * Set Pagination for shortcodes custom loop on single-pages.
     * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
     */
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'kli_wc_pre_get_posts_query' ); 
    function kli_wc_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        // Get paged from main query only
        // ! frontpage missing the post_type
        if ( is_main_query() && ( $query->query['post_type'] == 'product' ) || ! isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) ){

          if ( isset($query->query['paged']) ){
            $woocommerce_loop['paged'] = $query->query['paged'];
          }
        }

        if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
            return;
        }

        $query->is_paged = true;
        $query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
        $query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
    }

    /** Prepare Pagination data for shortcodes on pages
     * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
     */
    add_action( 'loop_end', 'kli_query_loop_end' ); 
    function kli_query_loop_end( $query ) {

        if ( ! $query->is_post_type_archive || $query->query['post_type'] !== 'product' ){
            return;
        }

        // Cache data for pagination
        global $woocommerce_loop;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['paged'];
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'] = $query->found_posts;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'] = $query->max_num_pages;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'] = $query->post_count;
        $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'] = $query->current_post;
    }
    /**
     * Pagination for shortcodes on single-pages 
     * @uses $woocommerce_loop;
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_template_part', 'kli_wc_shortcode_pagination' ); 
    function kli_wc_shortcode_pagination( $template_name ) {
        if ( ! ( $template_name === 'loop/loop-end.php' && is_page() ) ){
            return;
        }
        global $wp_query, $woocommerce_loop;
        if ( ! isset( $woocommerce_loop['pagination'] ) ){
            return;
        }
        $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
        $wp_query->query['paged'] = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['paged'];
        $wp_query->max_num_pages = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['max_num_pages'];
        $wp_query->found_posts = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['found_posts'];
        $wp_query->post_count = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['post_count'];
        $wp_query->current_post = $woocommerce_loop['pagination']['current_post'];

        // Custom pagination function or default woocommerce_pagination()
        kli_woocommerce_pagination();
    }   
    /**
     * Custom pagination for WooCommerce instead the default woocommerce_pagination()
     * @uses plugin Prime Strategy Page Navi, but added is_singular() on #line16
     */
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10);
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'kli_woocommerce_pagination', 10);
    function kli_woocommerce_pagination() {
        wp_pagenavi(); 
    }
}// END WOOCOMMERCE
}// END FRONTPAGE
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `[recent_products limit="12" columns="4" paginate="true"]`. This shortcode limit 12 means maximum 12 post on a page. more info woocommerce doc